# VisError message for a CZM simulation by Abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

I am going to extract Von Mises stress of cohesive elements of a adhesively bonded joint in Abaqus. I defined both node and element sets for the adhesive layer (cohsive elements). I used the following function to extract the stress results:

```
  session.xyDataListFromField(odb=odb, outputPosition=NODAL, variable=((
      'S', NODAL,((COMPONENT, 'Mises'),)), ), 
       nodeSets=("ADH", ))
```

I have faced with VisError: No xy data was extracted using the provided options, while I see the values of stress for each node in visulisation.

Also, when I use elementSets instead of nodesets as following, this problem is solved and Python gives me the results, but I prefer to obtain the stress using Nodal position, Not INTEGRATION_POINT. I would be very grateful, if you could help me.

```
   session.xyDataListFromField(odb=odb, outputPosition=INTEGRATION_POINT, variable=((
      'S', INTEGRATION_POINT,((COMPONENT, 'Mises'),)), ), 
       elementSets=("ADH", ))
```